# Is there a way to allow nested partition tables?

Tags: partition, partition-table

I'm looking to do something along the lines of

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb # create 2 partitions
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb1 # create 2 more
```

and end up with something along the lines of

```
[daffy@daffydesk ~]$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb           8:16   0  27.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0  13.9G  0 part
  └─sdb1p1      8:17   0   6.9G  0 part
  └─sdb1p2      8:17   0   7.0G  0 part
└─sdb2        8:17   0  13.9G  0 part
```

Is this even theoretically possible?

Comment: [May I ask why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? It's totally possible to create partition tables this way, but tools and OSs won't expect the inner one(s) and they won't pick it up, I think. You probably will be able to create devices by manually invoking `partx` or `kpartx`. In the worse case you can analyze the nested structure by yourself and `mount` with `offset` and `sizelimit`. What have you tried?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This is definitely not an XY problem, the goal is the question itself, for experimentation purposes. I've tried `fdisk /dev/sdb` to make the base partitions, then `fdisk /dev/sdb1` to make the nested partitions. fdisk errored when informing the kernel of the new partitions, and `partprobe /dev/sdb1` errored in a similar way. I have not tried partx or kpartx. The only way I've found to access the nested partitions is to mount `/dev/sdb1` as a loopback device and then mount `/dev/loop0p1`, but that doesn't get to the heart of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `kpartx -a /dev/sdb1` makes `/dev/sdb1p1` appear in `lsblk` but `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1p1` says that `/dev/sdb1p1` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. Check `/dev/mapper/`. Your OS and the tools are not well prepared to handle such tricks automatically and consistently.

Comment: Have you consider of use LVM?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible, because that's not how partitions and partition tables are interpreted by operating systems. That's because the approach simply isn't very good, and it breaks assumptions about structures of partitions, as well¹.

If you just want *more* partitions (in arbitrary order of creation) than the 1983 (!) MBR scheme allows, you just use GPT (which is only 20, not nearly 40 years, old), which is natively supported by modern firmware (since at least 2010). No sense in bending an obsolete scheme if there's a better, supported-everywhere alternative².

If you actually want to divide the space within a block device, device mapper and LVM are the tools designed for that. So, for that use case it also makes no sense to put MBR partition tables in MBR partitions.

The one case where that's actually useful is if you wanted to take a partition and use it as image of a full drive for a VM. Then, you'd just use the loopback device method you mentioned. Whether or not lsblk displays things as hierarchical doesn't really matter, that's just a displaying thing. However, in practice, people don't do that, either. They just use an image file residing on a normal file system (typical desktop usage) or block storage, coming either in via LVM, or via network storage (CEPH, …).

---

¹ There's a Volume Boot Record at a fixed position on a proper MBR partition, and that will clash with you putting an MBR partition table there. However, modern OSes don't care about VBRs...  but they don't support bending over backwards a 37 years  old partitioning scheme designed for hard drives of 2MB size, either.

² It's also a bit funny that something so utterly designed for specific hardware, an IBM PC of 1983, is still a commonly available partitioning scheme on *all* platforms, be it an x86_64 with terabyte disks or a MIPS router with 4MB of flash memory.